# Magic Dirt on ME : This ain't something unusual

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Obsessed with the color white,

Stroked left and right,

Giving the lessons of life,

Still left with dirt inside,

Take your take and tell what am I?

Time for a hint.. so here it goes..

> The whiter I  get more the dirty I am.

Comment: @noedne yes :)..

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't stop thinking of the Carlton Dance.

Comment: You might want to narrow down all the possible answers with a hint. It is quite broad now.

Comment: Will give a hint in 1 hour..

Comment: To make the question even clear I edited the Title as well.. to add a few more details..

Comment: For people who stumble on this and are confused: @Maniraj later clarified that they _accidentally_ misspelled "ain't"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a

> Chalk Board or a Black board

Obsessed with the color white,

> White chalk goes on it.

Stroked left and right,

> Drawing left to right.

Giving the lessons of life,

> They are in schools.

Still left with dirt inside,

> There is residue left on them.

Take your take and tell what am I?

> Umm, I am not sure.

The whiter I get more the dirty I am.

> And it does get dirty when white goes on it because it is not black anymore.

Comment: Correct answer 

Comment: I still don't get the ai'nt bit.

Comment: It was used as a framing part for the puzzle.. :)

Comment: How is it a framing part?

Comment: @Maniraj - Not to take anything away from QuantumTwinkie's answer, but you could have given Clarkey252 a bit of a nudge that he/she was heading in the right direction with [Clarkey252's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66207/33080).

Comment: I guess the hint was public for everyone.. and I had this thing in my mind from the starting that as soon as I'll give the hint the question will become a piece of cake .. so it was just the matter of time that Quantum saw the hint and drove towards the right answer .. @Phylyp

Comment: @PL457 This ai'nt something unusual means that this is not something unusual i.e. something usual and common which is the answer of this riddle. .. I latter realized that I typed the spelling of ain't wrong .. apology for the same.

Comment: @PL457 .... Phylyp understood the title very well although the approach was wrong but the understanding was correct . See the explanation he gave for the title .

Answer (score 18):

I think you are:

> Chalk

Explanation:

Obsessed with the color white,

> Chalk is usually white (not too sure about the obsessed bit)

Stroked left and right,

Giving the lessons of life,

> Reference to teaching

Still left with dirt inside,

> Chalk often has small amounts of impurities

Take your take and tell what am I?

> I think this refers to the board used in filming to mark takes (which were traditionally written on with chalk)

Comment: Good guess.. but its not the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Possibly:

> a book

Obsessed with the color white,

> Papers are mostly white

Stroked left and right,

> the writings

Giving the lessons of life,

> it is a source of communication

Still left with dirt inside,

> when it is old

Comment: good guess .. but alas this is not the answer :)

Comment: And there I thought talking to other people was the main source of communication... Guess I should book with other people more often!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Correction fluid?

Obsessed with the color white,

> Correction fluid is white and it is used as a drug.

Stroked left and right,

> To cover a mistake you stroke the white-out on it

Giving the lessons of life,

> Uhm, it's like a punishment for the mistake?

Still left with dirt inside,

> The mistake is only covered, but it's still there

Take your take and tell what am I?

As for the hint and the title:

> They both contain a mistake to be covered with correction fluid!

Comment: Ah, I wrote this answer while the correct one wasn't accepted yet!

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

> An iPhone

Obsessed with the color white,

> Apple devices are often white.

Stroked left and right,

> Touch phones are often controlled by swiping.

Giving the lessons of life,

> You can use it to look up information, or ask Siri (the "ai" in the question title).

Still left with dirt inside,

> Silicon from which integrated circuits are made.

Comment: Hahaha.. no.. not an IPhone 

Comment: Why you think it's iPhone, your answer seems to be Smart Phone :P

Comment: @NiranjPatel My impression is that most non-Apple devices tend to be silver or black.

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> **TOOTHBRUSH**

Title: *Magic Dirt on ME : This ai'nt something unusual*

> The magic dirt is the paste used with a toothbrush, paste has a gritty feeling
>  Nothing unusual about a toothbrush & toothpaste, it is a daily use item

Obsessed with the color white,

> Whiter teeth are a big selling point of toothbrushes (and toothpaste)

Stroked left and right,

> The brushing action

Giving the lessons of life,

> Brushing one's teeth is among the earliest lessons from a parent to a child

Still left with dirt inside,

> Toothbrushes hold germs *(slight guess here!)*

Take your take *(I presume this is take your time?)*

> Take your time brushing, don't rush it

HINT

> *The whiter I get more the dirty I am.*
>
>  Toothbrushes fade with use, meaning that coloured bristles lose their colour *(bit of a guess again!)*

Comment: Good attempt .. but not the answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial idea:

> a Snowflake

Obsessed with the color white,

> It is!

Stroked left and right,

> When it rains.

Giving the lessons of life,

> ???

Still left with dirt inside,

> It's made with dust inside: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake

Comment: you took a wrong road.. not the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but may be answer is:

> Cigarette

Obsessed with the color white,

> Cigarette is almost white

Stroked left and right,

> ???

Giving the lessons of life,

> Will give lesson of life when health problem.

Still left with dirt inside,

> When we do smoke then dirf left inside our body.

Comment: Not the right answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

My Guess:

> A Beard, or more specifically an old man's beard

Obsessed with the color white:

> Beards usually turn white as people get older

Stroked left and Right:

> People tend to stroke their beards when thinking

Giving he lessons of life:

> If talking about an older person, they would have much more life experience and can give out lessons of life

Still with dirt left inside:

> Not too sure about this one!

Take your take and tell what I am:

> Beards take time to grow

Comment: No.. not the right answer.. seemingly you've a wrong approach